# rclcpp::Rate doesn't use ROS time (use_sim_time)

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that `rclcpp::Rate` uses `std::chrono::system_clock`, which of course doesn't use ROS time, so it doesn't honor `use_sim_time`.

Any plans to add a version of `Rate` that uses ROS time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319510/rclcpp::rate-doesn%27t-use-ros-time-(use_sim_time)/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2019-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it's ticketed at: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/465 If anyone has time to help out with a proposed implementation it would be appreciated.

There's several other related enhancements we're tracking at: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/530

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1